# Is it possible to reduce file upload size in community builder > User Profile > Upload Photo?

Tags: napili, community-builder

Is it possible to reduce file upload size in community builder > User Profile > Upload Photo ?

[image]

Comment: Reduce the file size, or its dimensions?

Comment: File size ? Instead of 16 MB, I want to make 2 MB as per client requirement

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the Out of the Box component, if you would like to be able to limit the file size upload for this, you will need to create your own component.

The only file sizes you can limit in communities are specified in [Limit Files in Your Community]

Which is for Files ([lightning:fileUpload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm)) and other related uploadable documents via the community, not the Profile picture.

> ...The maximum file size you can upload is 2 GB. In Communities, the
>   file size limits and types allowed follow the settings determined by
>   community file moderation.

[Limit Files in Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_file_limits.htm&type=5)